# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails in web app with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a web application in which I have a registration form, and when I try to add a user, I get the following error. [error text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22OEi.png) 
My user entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_user")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Size(min=2, message = "At least 5 characters")
    private String username;
    @Size(min=2, message = "At least 5 characters")
    private String password;
    @Transient
    private String passwordConfirm;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public User() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getRoles();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPasswordConfirm() {
        return passwordConfirm;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Role entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "t_role")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Transient
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;
    public Role() {

    }
    public Role(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationComtroller {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());
        return "registration";
    }

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") @Valid User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }
        if (!userForm.getPassword().equals(userForm.getPasswordConfirm())){
            model.addAttribute("passwordError", "Паролі не співпадають");
            return "registration";
        }
        if (!userService.saveUser(userForm)){
            model.addAttribute("usernameError", "Користувач з таким іменем вже існує");
            return "registration";
        }

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

UserService

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        return user;
    }

    public List<User> allUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public boolean saveUser(User user) {
        User userFromDB = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

        if (userFromDB != null) {
            return false;
        }

        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(new Role(1L, "ROLE_USER")));
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
        return true;
    }


    public boolean deleteUser(Long userId) {
        if (userRepository.findById(userId).isPresent()) {
            userRepository.deleteById(userId);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public List<User> usergtList(Long idMin) {
        return em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id > :paramId", User.class)
                .setParameter("paramId", idMin).getResultList();
    }
}
```

and html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>registrat</title>
    <link th:href="@{/resources/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class ="regblock">
<h2>Реєстрація</h2>
<form action="/registration" th:action="@{/registration}" th:object="${userForm}" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" placeholder="Username"
                    autofocus="true">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" th:field="*{passwordConfirm}"
                    placeholder="Confirm your password">
    </div>
    <div th:if="${passwordError}">
        <p th:text="${passwordError}"></p>
    </div>
    <div th:if="${usernameError}">
        <p th:text="${usernameError}"></p>
    </div>
    <button class="regbtn" type="submit">Зареєструватися</button>
    <button class="regbtn" onclick=" window.location.href = '/index'">Головна</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Before that, the code using JSP worked fine, but when I decided to migrate the project to Thymeleaf and finish it, the following happened.